# Excel Function: How do I concatenate String ignoring comma and NULL values

Tags: excel, function

How do I concatenate below String ignoring comma and NULL values from different cell from A1 to F1.

```
 NULL   NULL    Welcome  NULL    NaiSen     NULL
```

My final result should be: Welcome,NaiSen

I tried using below function but got #VALUE!

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(SEARCH("NULL",A1:F1),"",""))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below idea:

```
    =CONCATENATE(IF(A1="null","",CONCATENATE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""),",")),
IF(B1="null","",CONCATENATE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",""),",")),
IF(C1="null","",CONCATENATE(SUBSTITUTE(C1,",",""),",")),
IF(D1="null","",CONCATENATE(SUBSTITUTE(D1,",",""),",")),
IF(E1="null","",CONCATENATE(SUBSTITUTE(E1,",",""),",")),
IF(F1="null","",SUBSTITUTE(F1,",","")))
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. It workded but when combining more than one cell it missed to insert comma(,).

Comment: Got this result = ,,Welcome,,NaiSen. I should clean the value now. Again got extra unnecessary commas.

Comment: I think its fine now :)

Comment: Wow you made my job very easy. :). Still had one issue of extra comma at the end if last cell is NULL. I can clean last comma using RIGHT function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a user defined VBA function like this

```
Function concatFunc(v As Range) As String
    Application.Volatile True
    Dim c
    Dim s As String
    For Each c In v
        If IsError(c) = False And CStr(c) <> "," Then
            s = s & CStr(c)
        End If
    Next
    concatFunc = s
End Function
```

Insert the code in VBA like this:
Alt-F11, insert module, paste in the code

Then call the function from the worksheet like this example:
 =concatFunc(A1:F1)

It then works like any other built-in Excel function.

Comment: I am not much aware of how to call VBA function from sub().

Comment: Alt-F11, insert module, paste in the code, then call it from the worksheet like this example: =concatFunc(A1:F1)